# Getting invalid email error when I try to update a user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider

I am trying to update the Comments for a user but when I try using the code below:

```
MembershipUser User = Membership.GetUser(UserName);
User.Comment = "Whatever...";
Membership.UpdateUser(User);
```

It throws the error:

> The E-mail supplied is invalid.

I've checked the email right before I call `UpdateUser` and it's fine.  Can anyone see why this would be happening?

**UPDATE:**

Stack trace -

```
[ProviderException: The E-mail supplied is invalid.]
   System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider.UpdateUser(MembershipUser user) +1583
   System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.Update() +111
   Security_Login.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\V1\VerbalInk.Web\Security\Login.aspx.cs:40
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +115
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +140
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +29
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2981
```

Comment: what'd you get for the User object's email? could it be that the record in your resource is saved in an invalid state, therefore it can load, but it cannot save...

Comment: Please provide the full stack trace of the error as that might add more information that just E-mail is invalid.

Comment: @NathanTregillus, I've checked the email right before I call `UpdateUser` and it's fine.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic, sure.  I don't think there is much that is helpful there, but I included it above just in case.

Comment: I am betting you can't supply the email address here, but are you sure it is actually a valid email? did you make sure there are no invisible characters in the string, or special characters in the username?

Comment: The email is legit.  Check my answer below.  Had to do with duplicate email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

There is possibly `Duplicate Email Address` in database. if you set `requiresUniqueEmail` to false 
in `Membership Connection String`, set it to `true`.

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" applicationName="blah" 
connectionStringName="balh" enablePasswordReset="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
minRequiredPasswordLength="5" passwordAttemptWindow="15" passwordFormat="Hashed"    
requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" **requiresUniqueEmail="true"** 
type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" />
```

Comment: Yes, this caused due to duplicate email. Adding requiresUniqueEmail="false" in connection string in web.config solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to have been caused by there being another record in my aspnet_Membership table that had the same email address as the record I was trying to update.  This is a testing database so I'm guessing I must have added it manually or something a while back, because with the current system it isn't possible to create duplicates.

For some reason they have a pretty misleading error message that suggests there is something wrong with the email address when, in fact, the issue is related to duplicate emails.

Hope this can help someone in the future.